# How to create a discord.js bot command and find it anywhere in the response from a user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Right now I have it so below if just the bots username is said, I'd like for if a user said the bots username anywhere below in a message the bot would see it.

Likewise this would be a learning experiment for me to understand how to do this with other words as well, like how to find a message with AAPL inside of it, my next step would be to find it in lower case or with one letter capped, etc.

```
 if (message.content.startsWith("<@554504420206051328>")) {
    message.channel.send('My advice to you, is buy AAPL.');
  } else
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.includes()` function is the one you are looking for :

```js
if (message.content.includes("<@554504420206051328>")) {
  message.channel.send('My advice to you, is buy AAPL.');
}
```

You can check this function [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) if you want more information.

---

Now for the second part of your question (searching for `AAPL` in a message), it is practically the same as the first :

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("aapl")) {
  message.channel.send('I found AAPL');
}
```

The [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) function puts the content of the message caught in lower case. So when you are looking for `aapl`, you are actually looking for `AAPL`, `aapl`, `Aapl`, etc.

Comment: @artvandelay my pleasure :) If you want it case sensitive, you need to remove the `toLowerCase()` part

Comment: Wow -- that seemed so easy, not sure how I missed it. I'm also sure though since this is just me starting out that all my bot replys probably shouldn't be followed by and else and started with an If, lol. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry for additional question... If I use it here and I want it to see don't and dont incase of a spelling, do i just need to duplicate the reply here so that it catches the mistake, or do i need to go as deep as a regex? 
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("I don't want no scrub")) {
    message.channel.send("a scrub is a guy who can't get no love from me");
  } else

Comment: @artvandelay handling a spelling mistake is really hard to do. The easy way would be to duplicate the reply to catch every mistake but it is a lot for not much and you may forget/miss some spelling mistakes. The same problems would apply using a regex

Comment: Thanks -- new here so sorry if these questions are... noobish, haha. appreciate all your help, if you have any good resources or samples/startup boilerplates (if they even exist) for discord bots please lmk. again, thank you.

Comment: @artvandelay as new to discord.js bot as you :) though I suggest checking the [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) or [Github public repos](https://github.com/topics/discord-js-bot). If this answer worked for you, consider marking it as accepted

Comment: Also -- what about one letter be capitalized and another not from the person issuing the message? Will LowerCase() catch that? seems to not like it so far if the first letter is capped

Comment: @artvandelay weird, `toLowerCase()` should put **all** letters to lower case and you should not have this problem